Visual Studio builds 1 project very long
I have Windows Forms project that takes over 2 minutes to build. It is the only project in the solution. Output window reaches the log message:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe  /noconfig
/unsafe+ /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /platform:x86
/warn:5 /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva-
...

Here it hangs for over 1,5 minutes. Then it finishes in 2-3 seconds.
I already tried to:

set copyLocal to false for all references dlls
clear bin, obj, .vs folders
add project folder to antivirus exception and even disable it completely
turn off windows search indexing for the project folder
deleting files/folders in the AppData temp directory
disabled hardware graphics acceleration (Tools > Options > Environment)
disabled source control plugin (Tools > Options > Source Control > Git to None)
disabled auto recover (Tools > Options > Auto Recover) reinstalling
disabled all VS Extensions
disable restoring of Nuget packages

The MSBuildLog shows CoreCompile step as the most time consuming. The Procmon shows a NotifyChangeDirectory operation lasting 1,5 minutes which seems like a reason. The operation details mention over 460 files in these locations:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\

How to tell which one is the problem?
There are also near 400.000 registry operations to:

HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
\REGISTRY\A{some guid}\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_82b16ce3

As a test I've created a virtual machine with Windows7x64 and VS2015,VS2017,VS2019 and it builds the project in 1-2 seconds.
Then Windows10 clean install VS2019 build time 1-2 seconds and VS2022 build time 2-4 minutes. Will try to find differences between VS2019 and VS2022 that result to slower build time

rather than wasting your time finding a solution (even if it's simple), I would suggest you just a clean install of visual studio, and set it up probably. (a couple of minutes may save you a couple of days searching for solution).

@iSR5 it was done as well, clean installs, different devices

Microsoft provides many methods to optimize performance. You can try them according to the methods in the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-performance-tips-and-tricks?view=vs-2022] and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/visual-studio-2022-launch-event/tips-and-tricks-optimizing-build-performance?source=recommendations. If that still doesn't work, this may be a problem with a specific version of VS. Try using the previous version of VS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#fixed-version-bootstrappers

Have you tried analyzing a binary log? https://msbuildlog.com

@CodyLiang thanks! I tried everything from the first link. The second link goes to VS2022 main page for some reason. I installed VS2019 with only packages needed for desktop development (2,7Gb) and it completes the build in 2 seconds. I think it's not worth looking further

@Lennart It shows CoreCompile step as most time consuming step and there's no option to expand it and see more details

It's normal that the second link goes to the VS2022 main page. I don't understand why you think it's not worth investigating further. According to your description, your problem occurs in VS2022. Shouldn't the problem be handled in VS2022?

Can you create a new project and import the source files into this fresh project?
